# setter and getter methods for final variables

Tags: java

I have a `final variable`, for which I have to write setter and getter methods.
I am not sure how to write these methods for `final` variable.

My variable be like:

```
public class {
    private final int age;    
    //setter and getter mothods
}
```

Comment: just like any getters and setters but you'll have to call your setter from constructor which would be pointless as you can initialize your final in the costructor by simple assignment

Comment: Getter method is like for any other field. Being `final` means it cannot be changed, so you can't do a setter method.

Answer (score 3):

You can't write a setter for final fields - you have to initialize them within your constructors.

The getter however is in no way different from a getter for a non-final field.

Answer (score 0):

Final **members** (variables) can not change their values once they are initialized, therefore, they must be assigned either when declared or at least in the constructor.

**Setters**

Since they can not change their initial value, there is no reason for definig a setter (not allowed).

**Getters**

On the other hand, since you can always read their values, there is no problem with defining and implementing getters

Answer (score 0):

**Setter** is used to set new value to a variable. But since the value of **Final Variable** can't be changed(i.e. remains constant), there is no use of setter. But **Getter** is allowed since getter is used to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

But for a final Object you can define setter and getter methods. This was my doubt actually and the context is a bit different in this question. Just answering it if it would be useful for someone else.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).